# Calling a reloadtableview() only once while using Firebase observe function

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

As the title says, I only want reloadtableview() to be called once. How do i approach this?
Here is my code:

```
var posts = [Post]() {
        didSet {
            posts.reverse()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }




func fetchData(){

            currentQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
                    var foundPosts = [Post]()
                    for snap in snapshot {
                        if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
                            let key = snap.key
                            let post = Post.init(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                            foundPosts.append(post)
                        }
                    }

                    self.posts = foundPosts
                    geoQuery?.removeAllObservers()
                }

        })
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    fetchData()
    // if I put "tableView.reloadData()" here, it wont load when the app opens for the first time
}
```

With this, the tableview is reloading everytime something is changed in the database. I want to only reload it once, but still have that observer there.

Comment: Since you are really asking that `reloadData` isn't called every time `posts` is updated, do use `didSet` to reload the table view.

Comment: Isn't that what I am already doing? Not really sure if I understand your answer.

Comment: Oops. Typo. I meant "do *not* use `didSet`".

Comment: okay. I have tried to move it to viewWillAppear, but then it won't load when I open the app (it reloads at other times when viewWillAppear is called).

Comment: Why don't you want the table reloaded each time `posts` is updated? How else is the table view going to show the correct data?

Comment: The tableview consists of several posts with different "vote" labels. I dont want the vote labels to constantly change or update because it will obviously look really messy when it constantly reloads. The reason I need posts updated, is that when the user likes a post, it uploads the likes from the database +1 like instead of the likes that is displayed on the phone at that moment +1 like.

Comment: I see there's an accepted answer but it seems overly complicated. There's no reason to use .value in this case as you said *I dont want the vote labels to constantly change* meaning that you are not using the data that's presented when something changed. Try using .observeSingleEvent, iterate over the child nodes and populate the array. When that for...loop is complete, reverse the array and reload the tableView. From there, when a user votes, update that node, read Firebase per fetchData and reload the tableView. Then you are only reloading when the user votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, the code below should do what you wanted. (Couldn't squeeze it into the comments)

```
var shouldReloadTableView = true

var posts = [Post]() {
    didSet {
        posts.reverse()

        guard shouldReloadTableView else { return }
        shouldReloadTableView = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me,but got me in to another problem: now posts.reverse() only gets called the first time the tableview reloads. At other occasions where I want the tableView to reload again it won't revers the posts. Any idea why?

Comment: This problem should not be related to the code that is added by this answer.